# Complete time.series using a function based on data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, function, data.table, tidyverse

I'm trying to learn more about `data.table` and the proper way to use it.

**Reproducible example**

This is my data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group1 = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 9), 
                 group2 = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
                 date   = as.Date("2023-01-01") + c(1,2,5,0,3,4,2,4,6,0,2,3,1,2,3,4,6,7),
                 x = rnorm(18), y = rnorm(18))
```

I want to add the missing dates in my dataset in each group.
Each group starts and ends at its own max and min date. Each group is defined by `group1` and `group2`.

**Task**

With Tidyverse I would do the following:

```
fill <- list(x=0, y=1)

out1 <- df |> 
  dplyr::group_by(group1, group2) |> 
  tidyr::complete(date = seq.Date(min(date), max(date), "day"), fill = fill) |> 
  dplyr::ungroup() |> 
  as.data.frame()
```

With data.table (I think) the solution would be:

```
library(data.table)
fill <- list(x=0, y=1)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
indx <- dt[, .(date = seq(min(date), max(date), "day")), by = list(group1, group2)]
dt <- dt[indx, on = .(date, group1, group2)]
if (length(fill)) dt[, names(fill) := Map(replace, .SD, lapply(.SD, is.na), fill), .SDcols=names(fill)]
out2 <- as.data.frame(dt)
```

I get the same result:

```
identical(out1, out2)
# TRUE
```

**Make a function out of the task**

Now, I want to create a function that takes in input a data.frame, a date column, multiple grouping columns and multiple columns to be filled.

With Tidyverse I would do:

```
complete_ts_tv <- function(df, date, ..., fill = list()){
  
  df |> 
    dplyr::group_by(...) |> 
    tidyr::complete({{date}} := seq.Date(min({{date}}), max({{date}}), "day"), fill = fill) |> 
    dplyr::ungroup() |> 
    as.data.frame()
  
}

identical(out1, complete_ts_tv(df, date, group1, group2, fill = fill))
# TRUE
```

How do I create a similar function with data.table?

**What I tried so far**

I found a solution but it doesn't work if the date column is actually called "date".

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group1 = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 9), 
                 group2 = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
                 date   = as.Date("2023-01-01") + c(1,2,5,0,3,4,2,4,6,0,2,3,1,2,3,4,6,7),
                 x = rnorm(18), y = rnorm(18))
fill <- list(x=0, y=1)

complete_ts_dt <- function(df, date, ..., fill = list()) {
  
  dt <- as.data.table(df)
  
  # Create a sequence of dates for each group combination
  indx <- dt[, .(date = seq(min(get(date)), max(get(date)), "day")), by = c(...)]
  
  setnames(indx, "date", date)
  
  # Perform a join on the original data.table to fill in missing dates
  dt <- dt[indx, on = c(date, ...)]
  
  # Replace NA values in the specified columns with the fill values
  if (length(fill)) {
    dt[, (names(fill)) := Map(replace, .SD, lapply(.SD, is.na), fill), .SDcols = names(fill)]
  }
  
  # Convert the result back to a data.frame
  out <- as.data.frame(dt)
  
  return(out)
}

# doesnt work!
complete_ts_dt(df, 
            date = "date", "group1", "group2", fill = list(x = 0, y = 1))
#> Error in get(date): invalid first argument

# works!
complete_ts_dt(df = dplyr::rename(df, DATE = date),
            date = "DATE", "group1", "group2", fill = list(x = 0, y = 1))
#>    group1 group2       DATE           x           y
#> 1       a      A 2023-01-02 -0.62645381  0.82122120
#> 2       a      A 2023-01-03  0.18364332  0.59390132
#> 3       a      A 2023-01-04  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 4       a      A 2023-01-05  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 5       a      A 2023-01-06 -0.83562861  0.91897737
#> 6       a      B 2023-01-01  1.59528080  0.78213630
#> 7       a      B 2023-01-02  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 8       a      B 2023-01-03  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 9       a      B 2023-01-04  0.32950777  0.07456498
#> 10      a      B 2023-01-05 -0.82046838 -1.98935170
#> 11      a      C 2023-01-03  0.48742905  0.61982575
#> 12      a      C 2023-01-04  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 13      a      C 2023-01-05  0.73832471 -0.05612874
#> 14      a      C 2023-01-06  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 15      a      C 2023-01-07  0.57578135 -0.15579551
#> 16      b      A 2023-01-01 -0.30538839 -1.47075238
#> 17      b      A 2023-01-02  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 18      b      A 2023-01-03  1.51178117 -0.47815006
#> 19      b      A 2023-01-04  0.38984324  0.41794156
#> 20      b      B 2023-01-02 -0.62124058  1.35867955
#> 21      b      B 2023-01-03 -2.21469989 -0.10278773
#> 22      b      B 2023-01-04  1.12493092  0.38767161
#> 23      b      C 2023-01-05 -0.04493361 -0.05380504
#> 24      b      C 2023-01-06  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 25      b      C 2023-01-07 -0.01619026 -1.37705956
#> 26      b      C 2023-01-08  0.94383621 -0.41499456
```

Any help?
I would be also interested in understanding how I can make my function more appropriate to a correct use of data.table.

---

**Update**: eventually I did like this. Does it look data.table-like enough?

```r
generate_dates <- function(date){

  seq.Date(min(date), max(date), by = "day")

}

complete_ts_dt <- function(df, date, ..., fill = list()) {
  
  dt <- as.data.table(df)

  # Create a sequence of dates for each group combination
  indx <- dt[, lapply(.SD, generate_dates), by = c(...), .SDcols = date]

  # Perform a join on the original data.table to fill in missing dates
  dt <- dt[indx, on = c(date, ...)]

  # Replace NA values in the specified columns with the fill values
  if (length(fill)) {
    dt[, (names(fill)) := Map(replace, .SD, lapply(.SD, is.na), fill), .SDcols = names(fill)]
  }

  # Convert the result back to a data.frame
  out <- as.data.frame(dt)
  
  return(out)
}
```

It works with my examples now.

Comment: `date` is a function in base. I haven't looked at your code in depth yet, but that could do some damage.

Comment: It might be more efficient to build `indx` in the following way:  


`unique_dt <- dt[, list(start = min(time_hour), end = max(time_hour)), by = c(...)]`
`seq_sizes <- as.integer(unclass(unique_dt$end) - unclass(unique_dt$start) + 1)`
`start <- unique_dt$start`
`unique_dt[, start := NULL]`
`unique_dt[, end := NULL]`
`indx <- unique_dt[rep.int(seq_len(nrow(unique_dt)), seq_sizes)]`
`indx[, (date) := .Date(sequence(seq_sizes, from = start))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with `data.table`, use `setDT` to convert `df` to a `data.table` by reference and then leave it that way. No reason to convert the function output back to a `data.frame`.

The join is a good approach. Although, I don't see the need for `lapply` or a helper function, and the `NA` fill can be simplified.

```
complete_ts_dt1 <- function(df, date, ..., fill = list()) {
  # create a data.table with all dates filled in
  dt <- setnames(
    setDT(df)[
      ,.(date = seq(min(.SD[[1]]), max(.SD[[1]]), "day")),
      c(...), .SDcols = date # group by ...
    ], "date", date
  )
  
  # join the original data to a data.table with all the missing dates filled in
  df[dt, on = c(..., date)][
    is.na(get(names(fill)[[1]])), names(fill) := fill # NA fill
  ]
}
```

An alternative approach:

```
complete_ts_dt2 <- function(df, date, ..., fill = list()) {
  setorderv( # sort the resulting data.table
    rbindlist( # bind the original data to a data.table with the missing dates
      list(
        setDT(df),
        df[ # create a data.table with the missing dates
          ,.(
            date = as.Date(
              sequence(as.integer(diff(.SD[[1]]) - 1L), .SD[[1]][-.N] + 1L)
            )
          ), c(...), .SDcols = date # group by ...
        ][,names(fill) := fill]
      ), use.names = FALSE
    ), c(..., date) # sort by ... and date
  )
}
```

`data.table` shines especially when performance is a concern. Timings:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  complete_ts_dt1 = complete_ts_dt1(df, date = "date", "group1", "group2", fill = list(x = 0, y = 1)),
  complete_ts_dt2 = complete_ts_dt2(df, date = "date", "group1", "group2", fill = list(x = 0, y = 1)),
  complete_ts_tv = complete_ts_tv(df, date, group1, group2, fill = list(x = 0, y = 1)),
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>             expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
#>  complete_ts_dt1  2.6638  2.7706  4.18143  2.93130  3.3745  9.7147    10
#>  complete_ts_dt2  1.4248  1.5499  2.31117  1.89895  2.0148  6.8276    10
#>   complete_ts_tv 20.3337 20.7733 24.21463 24.83460 26.8032 28.2474    10
```

---

Here's a full reprex to show that all the results are the same:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group1 = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 9), 
                 group2 = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
                 date   = as.Date("2023-01-01") + c(1,2,5,0,3,4,2,4,6,0,2,3,1,2,3,4,6,7),
                 x = rnorm(18), y = rnorm(18))

complete_ts_tv <- function(df, date, ..., fill = list()) {
  df |> 
    group_by(...) |> 
    complete({{date}} := seq.Date(min({{date}}), max({{date}}), "day"), fill = fill) |> 
    ungroup() |> 
    as.data.frame()
}

generate_dates <- function(date) seq.Date(min(date), max(date), by = "day")

complete_ts_dt <- function(df, date, ..., fill = list()) {
  dt <- as.data.table(df)
  indx <- dt[, lapply(.SD, generate_dates), by = c(...), .SDcols = date]
  dt <- dt[indx, on = c(date, ...)]
  if (length(fill)) {
    dt[, (names(fill)) := Map(replace, .SD, lapply(.SD, is.na), fill), .SDcols = names(fill)]
  }
  dt
}

complete_ts_dt1 <- function(df, date, ..., fill = list()) {
  # create a data.table with all dates filled in
  dt <- setnames(
    setDT(df)[
      ,.(date = seq(min(.SD[[1]]), max(.SD[[1]]), "day")),
      c(...), .SDcols = date # group by ...
    ], "date", date
  )
  
  # join the original data to a data.table with all the missing dates filled in
  df[dt, on = c(..., date)][
    is.na(get(names(fill)[[1]])), names(fill) := fill # NA fill
  ]
}

complete_ts_dt2 <- function(df, date, ..., fill = list()) {
  setorderv( # sort the resulting data.table
    rbindlist( # bind the original data to a data.table with the missing dates
      list(
        setDT(df),
        df[ # create a data.table with the missing dates
          ,.(
            date = as.Date(
              sequence(as.integer(diff(.SD[[1]]) - 1L), .SD[[1]][-.N] + 1L)
            )
          ), c(...), .SDcols = date # group by ...
        ][,names(fill) := fill]
      ), use.names = FALSE
    ), c(..., date) # sort by ... and date
  )
}

complete_ts_dt2(df, "date", "group1", "group2", fill = list(x = 0, y = 1))[]
#>     group1 group2       date           x           y
#>  1:      a      A 2023-01-02 -0.62645381  0.82122120
#>  2:      a      A 2023-01-03  0.18364332  0.59390132
#>  3:      a      A 2023-01-04  0.00000000  1.00000000
#>  4:      a      A 2023-01-05  0.00000000  1.00000000
#>  5:      a      A 2023-01-06 -0.83562861  0.91897737
#>  6:      a      B 2023-01-01  1.59528080  0.78213630
#>  7:      a      B 2023-01-02  0.00000000  1.00000000
#>  8:      a      B 2023-01-03  0.00000000  1.00000000
#>  9:      a      B 2023-01-04  0.32950777  0.07456498
#> 10:      a      B 2023-01-05 -0.82046838 -1.98935170
#> 11:      a      C 2023-01-03  0.48742905  0.61982575
#> 12:      a      C 2023-01-04  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 13:      a      C 2023-01-05  0.73832471 -0.05612874
#> 14:      a      C 2023-01-06  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 15:      a      C 2023-01-07  0.57578135 -0.15579551
#> 16:      b      A 2023-01-01 -0.30538839 -1.47075238
#> 17:      b      A 2023-01-02  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 18:      b      A 2023-01-03  1.51178117 -0.47815006
#> 19:      b      A 2023-01-04  0.38984324  0.41794156
#> 20:      b      B 2023-01-02 -0.62124058  1.35867955
#> 21:      b      B 2023-01-03 -2.21469989 -0.10278773
#> 22:      b      B 2023-01-04  1.12493092  0.38767161
#> 23:      b      C 2023-01-05 -0.04493361 -0.05380504
#> 24:      b      C 2023-01-06  0.00000000  1.00000000
#> 25:      b      C 2023-01-07 -0.01619026 -1.37705956
#> 26:      b      C 2023-01-08  0.94383621 -0.41499456
#>     group1 group2       date           x           y

res <- list(
  setDT(complete_ts_tv(df, date, group1, group2, fill = list(x = 0, y = 1))),
  complete_ts_dt(df, "date", "group1", "group2", fill = list(x = 0, y = 1)),
  complete_ts_dt1(df, "date", "group1", "group2", fill = list(x = 0, y = 1)),
  complete_ts_dt2(df, "date", "group1", "group2", fill = list(x = 0, y = 1))
)

identical(res[-4], res[-1])
#> [1] TRUE
Created on 2023-08-29 with reprex v2.0.2
```

Comment: excellent solution. I only changed as.Date with .Date in the last function coz it was giving me an error for the missing origin. Have they changed the default in a newer version? I'm running R 4.2.3

Comment: That's very possible. I'm running 4.3.0.

Comment: just a question... with the first method I retain the flexibility over the kind of sequence I can generate. It's enough for me to add a parameter to the function and I can easily swap from "day" to "month". Is there a way I can do the same using the second method?

Comment: Not with `complete_ts_dt2`, as it uses `sequence`, but it should work with `complete_ts_dt1` using the `by` argument in `seq` (currently hard-coded as `"day"`).

Comment: in the first method, if before the expansion I had any missing data in the first column, I would automatically overwrite the second column, am I right? coz you check the condition to fill only in the first column. have I understood correctly?

Comment: That is correct. If `x` or `y` could have `NA` values, you would correct the code depending on how you want the original `NA`s filled. If you want them filled the same way, use `lapply` in the line with the "NA fill line" comment. If you want them untouched, I would try adding them as columns in `dt` before the join.

Comment: now that I'm checking again: your second solution works only if the column is called "date" coz you dont have the renaming. However I feel the renaming is kinda dangerous. If I had another column already called "date" the function may perform in an unexpected way.

Comment: Yes, good catch. That was careless of me. The `rbindlist` call needs `use.names = FALSE`. See the update.